# Uploaded Files get overwritten in Dropbox

Tags: python, django, dropbox-api

I am trying to upload users files to DropBox in Django. When I use the built in 'open()' function, it throws the following exception:

```
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TemporaryUploadedFile
```

When I don't, the file gets uploaded successfully but is blank (write mode).

**UPLOAD HANDLER:**

```
def upload_handler(DOC, PATH):
    dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(settings.DROPBOX_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN)

    with open(DOC, 'rb') as f:
        dbx.files_upload(f.read(), PATH)
        dbx.sharing_create_shared_link_with_settings(PATH)
```

How do I upload files or pass a `mode` to DropBox API without it being overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

To specify a write mode when uploading files to Dropbox, pass the desired [`WriteMode`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/files.html#dropbox.files.WriteMode) to the [`files_upload`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_upload) method as the `mode` parameter. That would look like this:

```
dbx.files_upload(f.read(), PATH, mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode('overwrite')
```

This only controls how Dropbox commits the file (see [the `WriteMode` docs](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/files.html#dropbox.files.WriteMode) for info); it doesn't control what data you're uploading. In your code, it is uploading whatever is returned by `f.read()`, so make sure that's what you expect it to be.